# Why is: $1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{n-2} = 2^{n-1}-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I know that this might be elementary, but I don't know how to prove this equality, some hint?
I tried to extract the common two:

$$ 1 + 2^1+2^2 + \cdots + 2^{n-2} = 1 + 2(1+2+\cdots+2^{n-3}) $$

But this didn't help

Comment: Prove it by induction on $n$ using the formula you have there.

Comment: It's analogous to the fact that $99\cdots 9=10^n-1$, but with binary presentations.

Comment: Do you know the geometric sum?

Comment: @Fakemistake Yep $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{r} = \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ when $ 0<r<1$

Comment: Almost! Replace $n$ with $n+1$ on the rhs! Can you apply this formula with $r=2$?

Comment: @JoséMarín, First, your sum should start with $i=0$, not $i=1$. Second, the summand should be $r^i$, not $r$. Finally, the right-hand side should be $\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ (your exponent on the $r$ is wrong).

Comment: I don't think so because in that case the series probably diverges.

Comment: @JoséMarín It can't diverge, it's a sum of *finitely many terms*.

Comment: Ah ok! So I think now I know how to do it. I just need to replace this formula with the values in hand, sum till $n-2$ and replace $r$ by two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum $1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{n-2} $ doesn't change if we multiply it by $1$ i.e. $2-1$:

\begin{eqnarray}1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{n-2} &=& (1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{n-2})(2-1)\\
&=& (\color{red}{2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^{n-2}}+2^{n-1})-(1+\color{red}{2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^{n-2}})\\
&=&2^{n-1}-1
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(2^{k+1}-2^k)=2^{n-1}-1
$$
since the last series is telescoping,

Answer (score 2):

For a proof without words, draw a picture of the interval from $0$ to, say, $64$. Divide it in half to make two subintervals of length $32$, divide one of those in half, and so on. Look at what's left when you divide the last subinterval of length $2$.

I would accept this as a convincing argument (others might not) unless the assignment explicitly asked for a proof by induction.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Fakemistake](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173351/fakemistake) in the comments, the sum of a geometric series is $$\sum_{k=0}^{m-\color{red}1}a^k=\dfrac{a^m-1}{a-1}.$$

Apply this with $a=2$ and $m=n-1$.